# How to add to an array based on thread in C

Tags: arrays, c, pthreads

I'm trying to create an array that stores integers and is updated by one to multiple threads. As the threads get new data they need to add it to the array. What I would like to do is make an array and for each index in the array to be for an individual thread. My problem is I'm not sure how to identity threads besides pthread_self() and that doesn't seem useful here. I'm not sure if this is possible so even if the answer is it's not possible that helps.

Comment: You can pass an argument to each thread to tell it which index to use. Read the [pthread_create man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html). The last parameter is an arg that is passed to the thread's start routine.

Comment: hmm? this sounds like an xy problem. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Kaylum do you know if I can pass multiple parameters? I think that your idea would work but I'm already passing a parameter which is a pointer to a struct that they need data from. I tried to add an int to the struct so they could just take it from there but it seems like this is causing it to change the number I passed so that when I increment the number for the next thread it also updates it for all the threads before. If there was a way to copy the pointer data so that even if I changed the pointer later the variable I stored the data in would be unaffected I think that would also fix this

Comment: Antti I'm reading from a file and each time I get a number I pass it to a thread. The thread takes it and then sleeps for that amount of time. This is to simulate running multiple process. At the end I need to get all the data about how long each thread ran and then find the thread that ran for the longest and shortest amount of time.

Comment: Okay so some updates. I can pass proper id data and get the threads to keep it. The only problem is that I have to sleep for a second after making each thread which isn't ideal. This is because as I am doing it now there is an int field in the stuct that they grab their id from. However by the time the thread has started to memcpy the data the main thread has incremented that variable. This will work but it feels like a horrible solution and it makes the program take way longer especially as more threads get added. Any ideas or links are appreciated

Comment: I got it! What I ended up doing is just placing a wait condition that would be signaled when they were done getting the data. It was a pretty obvious solution but in case anyone struggled like me try looking at pthread_wait() and pthread_cond_signal().